# Replacing Text in excel fields

Tags: excel, replace, worksheet-function

I'm trying to change the acronyms for several countries into their full names.
The column of two letter acronyms that I want to replace looks like this:

```
HU
DE
DE
HU
PL
UA
CZ
SK
BY
EE
MD
SP
```

And in a separate sheet, I have a list of countries that correlate to the acronyms, which I wanted to use as the reference to speed up the process of replacing the acronyms to full names, like this:

```
A   Austria
BY  Belarus
BG  Bulgaria
HR  Croatia
CZ  Czech
DK  Denmark
EE  Estonia
GR  Greece
HU  Hungary
IE  Ireland
IT  Italy
LV  Latvia
LT  Lithuania
LX  Luxemburg
NL  Nederlands
PL  Poland
RO  Romania
RU  Russia
CS  Serbia
SK  Slovakia
UA  Ukraine
UK  United Kingdom
```

Using an IF and then a REPLACE formula, I wanted to replace the acronym, such as HU with Hungary. I was trying to do this with a formula which looked like this:

```
=IF(FR_HU_Consolidation!C2= B21, REPLACE(B22,1,100,D22), nothing)
```

in which, FR_UH...C2 is the first cell in the first sheet, in which I want to replace the HU acronym in sheet 1.

My task is to automate this process for a list of 100's of countries acronyms.

My idea was to use an IF statement to see if (sheet 1 acronym) == (sheet 2 (reference) acronym), then if it is true, replace the acronym with the respective country, else do nothing.

I'm not sure if this task is too complicated for excel, but if it is possible, it would save me a lot of time.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try to use a [VLOOKUP](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use a `VLOOKUP`. Suppose I have a list of acronyms in `Sheet1` on column A and a list of acronyms in `Sheet2` in columns A and B:

```
    Sheet 1                 Sheet 2
     A    B                 A     B
1    HU   =VLOOKUP(...      A     Austria
2    DE                     BY    Belarus
3    DE                     BG    Bulgaria
4    HU                     HR    Croatia
5    etc.
```

In column B of `Sheet1` I would then have the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, $Sheet2!$A$1:$B$4, 2, 0) //change range references as appropriate
```

Then all you need to do is drag the formala down the list of acronyms in `Sheet1` and copy and paste the results in column B into column A on `Sheet1`.

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: Thanks. This works well if I manually use VLOOKUP for each different acronym. But because I have so many acronyms to replace, I wanted to find a way of using the IF statement to go through the list in Sheet 2, verify if the the acronym in sheet 1 is equal to the first acronym in sheet 2 and then replace it with the full name. If the acronym  in sheet 2 does not correlate to that of sheet 1, I wanted to move down the list until acronym 1 = acronym 2. I need to make an automated process because every day I will be adding more countries to my first sheet, and I don't want to spend too much time.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve? If you input the `VLOOKUP` formula in `A1` in `Sheet1` and drag it down for all the cells you have acronyms for then this will give the appropriate country name. I appreciate it does not replace cthe acronym in col A but all you have to do is cut and paste. Not clear what is missing?